# Java Exercise: about the output

Tags: java

I need help with a particular Java code:

```
class A { 
  int i = 2; 
  int j = 5; 

  void set (int j) { 
    this.i = this.j; 
  } 
} 

class D extends A { 
  @Override 
  void set (int i) { 
    this.j = this.i + super.j; 
  } 

  public static void main (String[] args) { 
    A a = new D(); 
    a.set(5); 
    System.out.println(a.i+a.j); 
  }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why the output is `9`? thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm a new user, so please be clement, thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  To make your question better, please don't link to an image of your code.  Copy and paste it into your question.  Also, please explain _why_ you are confused about the output, so we know your thought process about it.  The best questions are [mcve].

Comment: I've added the code to your question via the [edit]-functionality (see just below the question) - that'd be what we'd like to see, next to what you've tried so far on your quest for understanding. In general: the more effort _you_ put into your question the less likely it won't be downvoted or closed and the more effort _we_ will be inclined to put into answering.

Comment: To check why that code's output is 9 you might step through it with a debugger. To make it short: the overridden method will set `j` to 7 and `i` will still be 2 so `7 + 2 = 9`. - It seems you're confused by the meaning of `this` and `super` here so you might want to read up on those, especially in relation to variables/fields and "variable hiding/shadowing".

Comment: Thanks Thomas, i regret my behavior, thanks a lot

Comment: You set `j` to `7`, but you never modify `i`. Also, in your `set` method, the fact that you're using the `this` keyword means that it's ignoring the parameter you pass in in favor of the existing value of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

**Why the output is 9**

Stepping through this problem, the main method is run from within class D.

1. `A a = new D();`
   A `D` Object is created called `a` and it extends class A. This means it inherits all of A's attributes. Including `int i = 2;` and `int j = 5;`
2. `a.set(5);`
   This calls the `set()` method within the `D` class
3. `this.j = this.i + super.j;`
   The statement executed in the `set()` method within the `D` class first refers to `this.i`. The `D` class inherits the `i` and `j` values from the `A` class that it extends; therefore, `this.i` = 2. Next, it refers to `super.j` which is directly referring to a value in the class it extends. In this case, the value `j` in the parent class `A` is equal to 5. Then it adds 2 + 5 = 7 and sets the sum to value `j` stored in the parent class.
4. `System.out.println(a.i+a.j);`
   This prints out the sum of the `i` and `j` values of the Object which are stored in the parent class it extends. So it prints 2 + 7 = "9".